# Any reason power supplies always use single sided PCB's?

Tags: power-supply, power, pcb

I am designing a PCB that has an onboard power supply switching module which requires filtering and protection on the input and output side. Its going to be a double sided PCB but I was wondering if the power supply section should be kept to a single layer. Just about every power supply I have seen always uses a single sided PCB.

The switching module is a 120VAC-24VDC. I am using a common mode choke, power factor correction cap, bypass caps, MOV, fuse and thermistor on the input side and filter cap, bypass cap and transient voltage suppressor diode on the output. I used a few topside traces to make everything fit neatly together. I imagine the single sided PSU's are solely for cost but is there anything I should be concerned about?

Comment: Here's an Apple charger teardown - http://www.arcfn.com/2012/05/apple-iphone-charger-teardown-quality.html - that thing uses two double-sided boards to achieve extra tight packing.

Comment: It is better to have more than one layer in terms of signal integrity. Search for grounding and ground routing. I am not an expert, so I cannot tell much.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's entirely about the cost. For most power supplies, the circuit is simple enough that it lays out with few, if any, crossovers required. In high-volume production, installing a few jumper wires or zero-ohm resistors is much cheaper than using a 2-sided PCB.

Answer (score 8):

As others have said it's cost, but you'll notice that these boards are different too, a light brownish color.  They are typically phenolic (as opposed to FR4 - fiberglass) so they are even less expensive.  They only have copper on one side -> even lower cost again and they are made via a pierce and blank method a punch like method (as opposed to drilling) which is even lower cost again.  Even a single sided FR4 board will be way more expensive than these boards.

Answer (score 5):

Cost, for sure.

My work experience has been at companies doing power supplies for industrial and datacom applications, and we generally use 4- or 6-layer boards to allow sufficient copper for the powertrain and sufficient layers to efficiently route the control circuitry as densely as possible. 1 and 2 layer approaches are fine where power density isn't a concern.

Answer (score -1):

If it were a 2 sided PCB, the vias would not be strong enough for just a few amps. Single-sided PCBs are for power supplies and high power appliances and simple circuits, and double sided PCBs are for computers and complex circuits.

Comment: If you need more current then a single via can handle, you can put several in parallel, so this is not a good explanation.